# How to interpret the expression « faire long feu » in the affirmative

Tags: expressions

> [original] : Notre petite ruse semble **avoir fait long feu**...

Compared to saying in the negative:

> Notre petite ruse **n’a pas fait long feu**... {didn’t last long}

Does the original sentence mean:

> "Our little trickery seems to have been short-lived {didn’t last long}."
>
> or : "Our little trickery has lasted for quite a while but seems to have come to an end at last."

Comment: I once wondered about this too, and indeed the positive and negative versions are different expressions: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_long_feu vs https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_faire_long_feu.

Comment: @AlanO'Donnell Cor bli... Who would've thought they were two different things?! So the English equivalent would be: "Our little trickery hasn't panned out the way we'd hoped". The question is: Did they come ever so close to pulling it off? Or it never really got off the ground?  I'm leaning towards the former, but what's your take? :)

Comment: Huh, I had never actually thought about that nuance. I don't actually know--I've always understood "faire long feu" to just mean "it didn't work", or "it fizzled", to match the French :), with no particular connotation about how close it came to working. But I'm curious what a French person thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a recurring ambiguity around these expressions.

The set expression ***ne pas faire long feu*** (to occur quickly) is generally well known. The issue is when people want to negate it.

***Ne pas ne pas*** faire long feu is logically simplified to just ***faire long feu*** and expected to mean "to last long, to take a long time to occur". This clashes with the other, less known, set expression identically written ***faire long feu***, which means "to eventually fail to achieve success".

A good example of such a confusion was [a reply by a former French Prime Minister](http://www.leparisien.fr/politique/ayrault-je-ne-suis-pas-impressionne-par-les-critiques-29-10-2012-2276073.php) (Jean-Marc Ayrault) to a *Le Parisien* newspaper reader question where *faire long feu* clearly means to both parties the opposite of *ne pas faire long feu*:

> Marc Ichbia: *— Pensez-vous **faire long feu** à Matignon ?*
>  
>   Jean-Marc Ayrault: *— **Oui, je pense**. L'action que je mène au gouvernement ne peut que s'inscrire **dans la durée**. Ce ne sont pas les yoyos de politique publique qui pourront résoudre les problèmes du pays. Ni en quatre jours que l'**on va régler les problèmes**.*

Comment: That's a fantastic example! I'm used to seeing the (positive) expression in relatively old books, so I had no idea the negative one was more common.

Answer (score 1):

[The real meaning of "faire long feu"](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_long_feu) is "to fail". "Ne pas faire long feu", has an unrelated meaning, and means "to not last/stay long": "Je n'ai pas fait long feu à cette soirée". The source above makes it unrelated, but it is possible that people just lost sight of the original meaning (the metal cartridge was invented a couple of centuries ago...).